# CodeKit Reload very slow

Tags: mamp, codekit

Codekit is so darn slow in reloading files. Why is that and what can I do against it?

I use MAMP3 on Yosemite with Chrome 39. Refresh delay is on 0 seconds.
I just have a bunch of php files and some less. Nothing extraordinary.
And it reloads the files with a delay of about 10seconds.

The LESS files are compiled very fast, but not the page reload. Internet sharing is deactivated.

What else could be the problem?

From time to time there is a message `Codekit connection is unstable`. But everything is hosted local. How can this be unstable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay. I figured out some things who slow down codekit significantly.

1. Mistake Nr. 1: Amount of Files

   - It seems to play a huge role how much files are added per project. My cms lives outside webroot but my less & css live inside webroot. So I threw in the whole project including the cms. This way I had no path conflicts (lazy me). This resulted in about 4000 Files. That is too much for codekit.
   - Solution: Still throw in the whole project but exclude the cms folders in codekit (Yeah I know RTFM)

[image]

2. Mistake Nr. 2: custom file extension

   - I started to work with twig files (after php was done) and miraculously browser refresh stoped working. Because Codekit doesn't doesen't seem to know twig. In order to keep Browser reload working one have to add twig into the Generig Page Extensions.

[image]

Thats it. Everything works just fine now.